# Program is repeating itself -can't figure out why

Tags: python, function, for-loop, repeat

This is my program so far...it takes a message (input from user) and tells the user how many A's are in the program, how many B's, etc. Except when I input a message such as "Dad", it'll tell me how many D's there are twice instead of just saying everything once. 
It says:

D ... 2

A ... 1

D ... 2

I want it to say:

A ... 1

D ... 2

How do I fix this without using zip, and without importing anything?

```
message=input("what is your message?").upper()
alphabet=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]
count=[0]*len(alphabet)
for i in message:
    if i in alphabet:
        count[alphabet.index(i)]+=1

for i in message:
    print (i,"...",count[alphabet.index(i)])
```

(Thanks to Uriel Eli for helping me get the program this far btw).

Comment: You could have alphabet as a string instead of an array of characters: `'ABCDE'` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't agree with your approach here. You have actually over complicated this. The proper way to solve this is to actually use a dictionary to keep track of all the letters in the string and keep a count every time the same character comes up. Note, this also sticks to the rule of not importing anything.

Furthermore, this removes the necessity to have a list of letters to check against as well.

Also, if you need to count upper and lower case characters separtely, do not call `upper` at the end of your input. Just remove it. If you have to count upper and lower case as the same character, then you can leave it.

```
message=input("what is your message?").upper()

d = {}

for c in message:
    if c in d:
        d[c] += 1
    else:
        d[c] = 1
```

Demo

```
what is your message?thisisastringofthings
{'H': 1, 'F': 0, 'O': 0, 'R': 0, 'G': 1, 'S': 3, 'T': 2, 'A': 0, 'I': 3, 'N': 1}
```

To provide an output similar to what you are expecting, you just need to iterate through your final result and print:

for character, count in d.items():
    print("{} ... {}".format(character, count))

Finally, just for the sake of showing *the* best way to do this, is to actually use `Counter` from `collections`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter("thisisastring")
Counter({'s': 3, 'i': 3, 't': 2, 'h': 1, 'n': 1, 'a': 1, 'r': 1, 'g': 1})
```

Comment: Thanks for editing it. You're obviously a lot more experienced than I am. Day one :)

Comment: No problem. We all started at some point. Question. Do you need to count lower and upper case separately, or does 'a' and 'A' count as the same?

Comment: It's the same -just the alphabet, I'm using uppercase when it's printing.

Comment: Then that is pretty much all you need. If the answer helped you, you should accept it by checking the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: @jason You're welcome. Good luck. Try not to get discouraged. You'll get the hang of it. Keep it up. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for future reference, and I know that you CANT import anything now. The best way probably would be:

```
from  collections import Counter
message=input("what is your message?").upper()
print(Counter(message))
# Counter({'D': 2, 'A': 1})
```

Comment: upvotes all around! :) Hope my message didn't come across as rude or anything. Just wanted to mention it in case you hadn't seen it.

Comment: @idjaw Its all good. Same/similar multiple anwsers are common when few ppl work at the same time on a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your second `for` loop is iterating through `message`, so if the user input `DAD` (well... after upper casing it), you're gonna get:

```
message == DAD
  i = D --> Shows 2
  i = A --> Shows 1
  i = D --> Shows 2 (again)
```

Maybe you'd want to iterate through `count`, keeping the index that you are iterating (to use it latter to match it with the `alphabet` list). Something like that:

```
for index, num_occurences in enumerate(count):
    if num_occurences > 0:
        print("Match found at i=%s which corresponds with alphabet[%s]=%s" %
              (index, index, alphabet[index]))
        print(alphabet[index], "...", num_occurences)
```

You should check what [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) does.

If you still want to iterate through `message`, you can do it, keeping track of what letter did you already display using an auxiliary [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) (so you don't show the same letter again)

```
already_shown_letters = set()
for i in message:
    if i not in already_shown_letters:
        print (i,"...",count[alphabet.index(i)])
        already_shown_letters.add(i)
```